# python inheritance: choose parent class using argument

Tags: python, oop

I'm having trouble designing some classes. I want my user to be able to use the Character() class by passing in an argument for the type of character (e.g. fighter/wizard).

Dummy code:

```
class CharClass():
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

class Fighter(CharClass):
    # fighter stuff
    pass

class Wizard(CharClass):
    # wizard stuff
    pass

class Character(): #?
    def __init__(self, char_class):
        # should inherit from Fighter/Wizard depending on the char_class arg
        pass
```

For example, after calling:
`c = Character(char_class='Wizard')`
I want c to inherit all the attributes/methods from the Wizard class.
I have lots of classes so I want to avoid writing separate classes for each, I want a single entrance point for a user (Character).

Question: can it be done this way? Or is this a silly way to approach it?

Comment: Not too silly, in fact, this is what OOP developers would call the `factory pattern` although I'd move it from a class to a function personally. `def get_character(character_type): ...`  would return an instance of one of your character classes.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mrfksiv/python-design-patterns-03-the-factory-86cb351c68b0

Comment: Does Character need to be a class or can it be a function which returns a Character Wizard/Fighter instance ?

Comment: I wanted a class, since I also want `Character` to inherit from another class (a `Race` class, so that you can create, e.g. a Human Wizard). I omitted this in the question to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the less known feature of the `type` function:

```
def Character(char_class):
    return type("Character", (char_class,), {})
```

`type` can be used to dynamically create a class. First parameter is the class name, second are the classes to inherit from and third are the initial attributes.

Comment: Surely we don’t want to create a new class every time!