# Choose which parent class inherit from in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm struggling into trying to choose the parent class to inherit from when creating a class without affecting any children classes.

There's a pyramidal structure of classes where, on the top, I try to choose where to inherit from: `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process` (specifying it with an argument on the children classes).

I've managed to do it only with the first level of this pyramid creating a function that returns the Base Class, code here:

```
class ProcessClass(object):
    '''A thread with different inheritance.
    '''
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        thr_type = kwargs.pop("thr_type","threading")
        print("HELLO", thr_type)
        if(thr_type == "threading"):
            new_cls = threading.Thread 
        if(thr_type == "multiprocessing"):
            new_cls = multiprocessing.Process
        instance = super(ProcessClass, cls).__new__(obtain_thread_class(new_cls))
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance

def obtain_thread_class(new_cls):
    class BaseClass(new_cls):
        """Class with its methods"""
        def __init__(self, daemon=False, *args, **kwargs):
            # THREADING
            super(BaseClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.daemon=daemon
        def hello(self):
            print("Hello World")
    return BaseClass
```

But now, when I try to inherit `ProcessClass` in a child class, this one looses all his properties, and the parameters can not be passed properly (i think this is due `__new__`).

The child example class is:

```
class ExampleClass(ProcessClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3="1", *args, **kwargs):
        self.list_args = [arg1, arg2]
        print("arg3 is", arg3)
        super(ExampleClass, self)
    def hello2(self):
        print("Hello from child!")
```

With this, if I execute:

```
a = ExampleClass(thr_type="threading")
print(type(a))
```

I obtain:

```
HELLO threading
<class '__main__.obtain_thread_class.<locals>.BaseClass'>
```

But then, i can only call `hello()` but not `hello2()`:

```
a.hello()
Hello World

a.hello2()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-2505bb83de52>", line 1, in <module>
    a.hello2()

AttributeError: 'BaseClass' object has no attribute 'hello2'
```

I think using `__new__` is the thing that is breaking children creation.

I've tried using also decorators, and seen something of `__metaclasses__` but before getting in deeper in those realms, I would like to know if there's something easier since I'm not that expert in python.

Also, I don't want this change to affect any of the program I'm running already, (many classes are inheriting from `ProcessClass`, but this is only `threading.Thread` by the moment). I'm trying to keep this change `unnoticiable` for the overall programs.

Comment: Instead of using inheritance, have you thought about using composition for your different process types?

Comment: Perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071752/python-inheritance-choose-parent-class-using-argument

Comment: This approach doesn’t make any sense: there is one class `ExampleClass`, which is not enough (if you want objects to actually have these derived classes as their types so that method lookup works), and there is a separate `BaseClass` for every *object* created by `ProcessClass`, which is also wrong.  Are you asking for help auto-generating classes or writing factory functions or what?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to decide simply the parent class of `ProcessClass` with a parameter. `BaseClass` was before inside `ProcessClass` but since I was returning a new class with the `__new__` i though of separating the methods and attributes needed in a base class and make that base class the one which decides its parent.

Comment: I think i'll go for composition as @JoshuaNixon said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i went with composition. Did not found how to choose inheritance in runtime. But this still works.

```
class ProcessClass(object):
    '''A thread with different inheritance.
    '''
    def __init__(self, thr_type="multiprocessing", *args, **kwargs):
        if(thr_type == "threading"):
            new_cls = threading.Thread
        if(thr_type == "multiprocessing"):
            new_cls = multiprocessing.Process
        self.thread = new_cls(*args, **kwargs)
    def start(self):
        return self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        return self.thread.run()
```